# Finding new point position after scaling

Tags: java, android, scaling

I scaled my canvas as following (in `onDraw`):

```
canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFocusX, mScaleFocusY);
```

My onScale function is:

```
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
    mScaleFocusX = detector.getFocusX();
    mScaleFocusY = detector.getFocusY();  
        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
    mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Now I get more points (using `onTouchEvent`) to create new `path` which eventually I want to draw.
`onTouchEvent` gives me x and y but doesn't take into account that a scale occurred.
How can I know where is the new position of x and y after the scaling?

Answer (score 1):

From your question it is not clear what you do with `mScaleFactor`, `mScaleFocusX`, `mScaleFocusY` when rendering you canvas.

But, basically you just need to reverse this process to calculate the original coordinates of the touch (or any other form of interaction).

So for example if you calculate the render coordinates like this:

```
float renderX = originalX * mScaleFactor + mScaleFocusX;
float renderY = originalY * mScaleFactor + mScaleFocusY;
```

so would need to use

```
float correctedTouchX = (touchX - mScaleFocusX) / mScaleFactor;
float correctedTouchY = (touchY - mScaleFocusY) / mScaleFactor;
```

to calculate the corrected (original) coordinates. If you use `mScaleFactor`, `mScaleFocusX`, `mScaleFocusY` in some other way, you need to reverse that.

---

UPDATE: It seems that [Canvas.scale()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#scale%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) first uses `mScaleFocusX` and `mScaleFocusY` to define a pivot point (i.e. offset) and then scale. So you probably need these formulas (maybe change a minus into a plus sign somewhere):

```
float correctedTouchX = touchX / mScaleFactor - mScaleFocusX;
float correctedTouchY = touchY / mScaleFactor - mScaleFocusY;
```

Comment: I send those variables to `canvas.scale`.... I do not use them (currently) in any other way